# VB.NET how to display proper data in combo box

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a combo box that contains the following

```
2017-2018
2018-2019
2019-2020
```

What I want to happen is that it must display the proper data on the combo box based on a specific date range. For example:

If the date range is June 1, 2017 between March 30, 2018
then the combo box should display `2017-2018`

If the date range is June 1, 2018 between March 30, 2019
then the combo box should display `2018-2019`

How do I do this approach?  Is it better to use a database for this or can it be hard-coded?

Comment: Whether the data comes from a database or not isn't really relevant. While this could be done in various ways, I'd suggest a data structure that contains the range start date, range end date and the text to display. That might be a `DataTable` populated from a database or a list of a custom type. It doesn't matter. Once you have a date, you can then loop through the list and compare your date to the limits of each range and then, when you find one that contains your date, you assign it to the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Date.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, dtDate)
    ComboBox1.SelectedItem = DoDate(dtDate)
End Sub

Private Function DoDate(ByVal dtInputDate As Date) As String
    Dim intYear As Integer = dtInputDate.Year
    If dtInputDate >= New Date(intYear, 6, 1) And dtInputDate <= New Date(intYear, 12, 31) Then
        Return CStr(intYear) & "-" & CStr(intYear + 1)
    ElseIf dtInputDate >= New Date(intYear, 1, 1) And dtInputDate <= New Date(intYear, 3, 30) Then
        Return CStr(intYear - 1) & "-" & CStr(intYear)
    Else
        MsgBox("ERROR: Date must be between 1 Jan and 30 Mar, or 1 June to 31 Dec.")
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: it works! wow! thanks!
I'm still trying to understand the if-elseif statements and trying to debug the code, but so far so very good!

Comment: Terrific! Let me know if you have questions.